# Four panel, image with borders

Tags: graphics, positioning, rules

I am trying to make a landscape PDF with borders (4) where I will place 4 figures. Ideally the line would be 3 point in width...I have attached a JPG of what I am thinking. I would like to place figures in the areas a-d.

[image]

Can someone give me a starting point?

Comment: And what margins and size should the page have? Must the images be centered inside each frame? Is this the only contents of the document or is this a special page in a portrait document?

Comment: Page should be A4 with 2 cm margins of top/sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following example I defined a new command `\FramedImage` with one optional argument (the options to be used in the optional argument of `\includegraphics`) and a mandatory one (the name of the image file). This command places its contents inside a `minipage` enclosed in a `\fbox` to obatin the frame:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand\FramedImage[2][]{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{2pt}% change according to needs
  \setlength\fboxrule{3pt}%
  \noindent\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr.5\textheight-1.5\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax][c]{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-1.5\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \end{minipage}}%
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\FramedImage{image1}\hspace*{-3pt}\FramedImage{image2}\\[-3pt]\offinterlineskip
\FramedImage{image3}\hspace*{-3pt}\FramedImage{image4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: This seems to rotate the images.. perhaps because the OP wanted landscape. What is required to use it in portrait?

Comment: The rotation issue was my mistake (not an issue). However, how about adding a), b), c), etc.?

Comment: @John With the possibility to cross-reference them? I think it would be better to open a follow-up question.